# Why segmentation fault is not thrown when I free the local variable pointed to NULL

Tags: c, operating-system, free

I was doing the exercise of Operating Systems: Three Easy Pieces chapter 14 Memory API.

And I am wondering why segmentation fault is not thrown when I didn't use the p variable?

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
  int* p = NULL;
  // if I print the p variable an segmentation fault is thrown.
  // but if I am not, nothing will happen.
  //printf("%d\n",*p);
  free(p);
}
```

Comment: It is defined that "If a null pointer is passed as argument, no action occurs." [link] https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_free.htm

Comment: But when I print it, an segmentation fault will be thrown.